# CF10 Twitter4j lookupUsers method was not found or method is overloaded

Tags: coldfusion, twitter4j, cfml

I am using CFML and Twitter4j to return timelines and lists.

I want to return the data from a call to `lookupUsers(java.lang.String[] screenNames)`
via Twitter4j.

I have tried the :-

```
strList = createObject("java", "java.util.ArrayList");
strList.add(strOriginUser);
originUser = t4j.lookupUsers(strList);
```

And :-

```
strUserString = JavaCast("String", strOriginUser);
originUser = t4j.lookupUsers(strUserString);
```

I know the t4j Object is working as I already use it to get timelines etc but here it is for completeness :-

```
public function init_twitter() {
    //CONFIGURE twitter4j
    configBuilder = createObject("java", "twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder");
    configBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(#application.twitter_consumer_key#);
    configBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(#application.twitter_consumer_secret#);
    configBuilder.setOAuthAccessToken(#application.twitter_access_token#);
    configBuilder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(#application.twitter_access_token_secret#);
    configBuilder.setIncludeEntitiesEnabled(true);
    configBuilder.setJSONStoreEnabled(true);
    config = configBuilder.build();
    twitterFactory = createObject("java", "twitter4j.TwitterFactory").init(config);
    variables.t4j = twitterFactory.getInstance();
    return this;
}
```

The twitter4j documentations is:-

> `ResponseList<User> lookupUsers(java.lang.String[] screenNames) throws TwitterException`
>
> Return up to 100 users worth of extended information, specified by either ID, screen name, or combination of the two. The author's most recent status (if the authenticating user has permission) will be returned inline. 
>   This method calls http://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json
>
> Parameters:
>
> `screenNames` - Specifies the screen names of the users to return.
>
> Returns:
>   `users`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to pass an `ArrayList` object into `lookupUsers` but that method only accepts `String[]` (an array of Strings) as an argument. So unless CFML does the conversion, I don't think it's going to work.

From a cursory glance at the ColdFusion docs, it looks like CFML can implicitly convert a CFML Array to a Java array, so perhaps the following would work:

```
screenNames = arrayNew(1);
screenNames[1] = 'Fry';

originUser = t4j.lookupUsers(screenNames);
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep on using a list there is an [`ArrayList#toArray(T[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29) which could be useful, although I can't say how useful that would be in the CFML.

**N.B.** Please excuse my CFML code snippet.

Comment: Perfect. I used :-
    screenNames = arrayNew(1);
    screenNames[1] = 'Fry';
    originUser = t4j.lookupUsers(screenNames[1]);

Now it works. Thanks